# how can i connect raspberry pi with pico H via modbus RTU?

Tags: modbus

i want to run raspberry pi as master and i need 10 Pico H as slaves via modbus RTU/serial communication and i don't know the code to i just want to run openplc in master and want to use slaves GPIO pins as Input/Output is anyone have wiring connections diagram and codes?